# ASP.NET Repeater - Evaluate Item as int?

Tags: asp.net, repeater

I'm trying to style a table row based upon a value in the databound collection (from LINQ to SQL) in my item template, however it's not working.

This is what I have so far:

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <% 
        string style = String.Empty;
        if ((string)DataBinder.Eval(Quotes.Cu, "Status") == "Rejected")
            style = "color:red;";
        else if ((string)Eval("Priority") == "Y")
            style = "color:green;";

        if (style == String.Empty)
            Response.Write("<tr>");
        else
            Response.Write("<tr style=\"" + style + "\"");                            
    %>

    <td>
        <%# Eval("QuoteID") %>
    </td>
    <td>
        <%# Eval("DateDue", "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}") %>
    </td>
    <td>
        <%# Eval("Company") %>
    </td>
    <td>
        <%# Eval("Estimator") %>
    </td>
    <td>
        <%# Eval("Attachments") %>
    </td>
    <td>
        <%# Eval("Employee") %>
    </td>
    </tr>
</ItemTemplate>
```

EDIT:

Sorry I didn't make this clearer! The problem is, It's throwing an error:

```
Databinding methods such as Eval(), XPath(), and Bind() can only be used in the context of a databound control.
```

Comment: Sorry, which line is not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please change this

```
<% 
   string style = String.Empty;
  ....
%>
```

by

```
<%#
   string style = String.Empty;
  ....
%>
```

Notice that I added `#`

Answer (score 0):

Which part is the int?  I don't see how the int part applies?  If the object is truly an int, you can always cast it to int as (int)Eval("Value"), or if a string, you can convert using int.Parse or int.TryParse (this is safer if its possible for the field to not be an int).

HTH.